# Re-scaling the outputs of a matrix completion algorithm

Tags: matrices, euclidean-geometry, normal-distribution, matrix-completion

In short: A matrix completion algorithm takes input values in the interval $(0,1)$. How to use this algorithm for inputs values in a larger interval?

In detail:
I am working on a problem that requires recovering missing distances of a partial distance matrix. To be more specific, I have a got a set of $n$ access points $X = \{(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)\}$ on a $2D$ plane in a $50m \times 50m$ area. The locations of the access points may change over time, and in an attempt to detect any change in their locations, real-time distance measurements (e.g., time of arrival technique) are done periodically between every pair of access points, and a [Euclidean Distance Matrix (EDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance_matrix) is formed. However, some of the elements in this computed EDM can be missing (e.g., two access points may go out-of-range from each other making distance measurement impossible).

We are trying to use an EDM completion algorithm "Rank alternation" proposed in [Dokmanic et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.07541.pdf)([Implementation code on GitHub](https://github.com/LCAV/edmbox)) to recover the missing distances of our measured EDM (Input: a partial EDM, Output: a complete EDM). However, the algorithm only takes input values in the interval $(0,1)$, while in our measured EDM each element (i.e., distance between two access points) ranges in the interval $(0,70)$ (in meters).

We can use [min-max normalization](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/normalization) to scale the elements of our computed EDM to take values in the interval $(0,1)$. Output of the "Rank alternation" algorithm will be a complete EDM (with the missing elements recovered), and the values of its elements will be again in the interval $(0,1)$.

Is there a way to translate these values back to the distances potentially ranging in $(0,70)$?

Comment: The document describing the algorithm is only available for purchase :(

Comment: @Andrei Updated the link - you do not need to purchase now - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the units of your points so that all distance values will be between $(0,1)$.

That is, if you original plane has coordinates $[0,50]\times [0,50]$, make a new coordinate system with corresponding set $[0,1/\sqrt{2}]\times [0,1/\sqrt{2}]$.  So, if you original point is $(x,y)$, where $x,y\in[0,50]$, then create a new coordinate $(x',y')=(x/(50\sqrt{2}),y/(50\sqrt{2}))$.  Then, the distance between each pair of points will be between $[0,1]$.

Once you have the completed distance matrix, multiply all values by $50\sqrt{2}$ to convert back to your original coordinate system.